# How to load CSV Data into Database using python and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, csv, sqlalchemy

I am trying to load a CSV file into a database with the following code :

```
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy as db
import pandas as pd
import csv
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

def main ():

  engine = db.create_engine('sqlite:///train_database.db',)
  connection=engine.connect()
  meta_data=db.MetaData()

  train_table=db.Table("train_table", meta_data,
                     db.Column("x",db.Float),
                     db.Column("y1",db.Float),
                     db.Column("y2",db.Float),
                     db.Column("y3",db.Float),
                     db.Column("y4",db.Float))

  meta_data.create_all(engine)

  engine = db.create_engine('sqlite:///train_database.db')
  meta_data=db.MetaData()
  connection=engine.connect()

  train_table=db.Table("train_table", meta_data,
                     autoload=True,
                     autoload_with=engine)

  session = sessionmaker()
  session.configure(bind=engine)
  s = session()

  try:
        train_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jacmanski/dataset/main/train.csv'
        train_data = pd.read_csv(train_url) 
        data_reader = csv.reader(train_data, delimiter=',')
        

        for i in data_reader:
            record = train_table(**{
                'x' : i[0],
                'y1' : i[1],
                'Y2' : i[2],
                'Y3' : i[3],
                'y4' : i[4],
            })
            s.add(record) #Add all the records

        s.commit() #Attempt to commit all the records
  except:
        s.rollback() #Rollback the changes on error
  finally:
        s.close() #Close the connection


if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

the result is I don't get any error message, but the table is not being filled with the values from the CSV file. What am I doing wrong ??

Also, I need to load another CSV file (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jacmanski/dataset/main/ideal.csv) into a table of 50 columns. How to create a table with 50 columns and insert the data into that table?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68894159/2144390